# JavaScript : Use of closure variable

Tags: javascript, html, closures

I am attempting to make this below html/javascript program work.
It basically runs two counters, the functionality that is not working is the reset counter option.

The 'initCounter' method initialises two counters with the given initial value.
Pressing on button 'Incr 5', 'Incr 3' will increment the value by either '5' or '3'. Pressing the reset button should reset the values to zero, which is not happening currently.

In the 'runCounter' method I am using a varaible 'localCxt' which will have the current value of the counter.

In the 'reset_fn' method I am resetting the 'localCxt varaible to zero, but this is not working, the counter value is not reset to zero.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var reset_fn;
function runCounter(initVal) {

    var localCxt = initVal;

    reset_fn = function reset() {
        localCxt = 0
    }
    return function (ctr) {
        localCxt += ctr;
        return (localCxt);
    }
}

function initCounter() {
    //get the initial value of the counter
    var val = parseInt(startInput.value);
    if (isNaN(val)){
        val = 0
    }

    ctr5 = runCounter(val);
    ctr3 = runCounter(val);

    document.getElementById("ctr5").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("ctr3").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("rst").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("init").disabled = true;
}

function displayCtr(ctr_val){
    var doc

    if (ctr_val == 5) {
        var val = ctr5(ctr_val)
        doc = document.getElementById("res5");
    }

    if (ctr_val == 3) {
        var val = ctr3(ctr_val)
        doc = document.getElementById("res3");
    }

    doc.innerHTML = val;
}

function resetCnts() {
    doc5 = document.getElementById("res5");
    doc3 = document.getElementById("res3");

    doc5.innerHTML = 0;
    doc3.innerHTML = 0;
    reset_fn();

    document.getElementById("init").disabled = false;
}

function start(){
    document.getElementById("ctr5").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("ctr3").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("rst").disabled = true;
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="start()">
<input type="text" id="startInput" value="0">
<button id="init" onclick="initCounter()">Initilaize</button>
<button id="ctr5" onclick="displayCtr(5)">Incr 5</button>
<button id="ctr3" onclick="displayCtr(3)">Incr 3</button>
<button id="rst" onclick="resetCnts()">reset</button>
<div id="res5" class="cl5">_</div>
<div id="res3" class="cl3">_</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Calilng `reset_fn()` will only ever reset the most recently created counter, because the `reset_fn` variable is set within the most recent call to `runCounter()`.

Comment: Ok, go it. is there any way to update the 'localCxt' (closure stack) of both the counter methods (ctr5, ctr3) at once from my 'resertCnts' method?

Comment: Please provide  a minimal example of no more than a couple dozen lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

there is one global reset_fn, being overridden each time the runCounter function is called.

Might I suggest that you reconsider your design? keep everything about the object inside the object, like so:

```
function Counter(value){
    this.context=value;
    this.reset = function() {this.context=0};
    this.addVal = function(val) {this.context+=val};
}
```

then create `var ctr5 = new Counter(5)` and go `ctr5.reset()` and `ctr5.addVal(ctr_val)`

you can also encapsulate all your document elements in the same object too.

update: 
as suggested in comments, you can add methods to a class using its prototype:

```
function Counter(value){
  this.context = value;
}
Counter.prototype = {
   reset: function() {this.context = 0},
   addVal: function(val) {this.context += val}
};
```

The main point is, to use an object for this problem. there are a magnitude of ways in Javascript to create objects and add properties and methods to them, which you can Google easily.

Comment: Seems to me the *reset* and *apply* functions should be on the prototype. And calling an *apply* method on an instance may be confused with calling *Function.prototype.apply*, perhaps it should have a different name?